# Extrinsic curvature, Gauss equation and Christoffel symbol contribution

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, curvature, adm-formalism

This question is in the context of geometry of hypersurfaces and ADM formalism. In a $4$-dimensional manifold, we define a $3$-hypersurface with space-like tangent basis $e_a$, $a=1,2,3$, and a normal time-like unit vector $\boldsymbol{n}$. Following Corichi's [notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.10103.pdf), he defines the extrinsic curvature as
\begin{align}
K_{ab}=\boldsymbol{n}\cdot ^{(4)}\nabla_a e_b\,,
\end{align}
where $\cdot$ is the dot product. In Eq. (3.27) of his notes, he writes the three-dimensional Christoffel symbol can be written as
\begin{align}
^{(3)}\Gamma_{abc}=e_a\cdot \,^{(3)}\nabla_c e_b\,.
\end{align}
With these two equations, he says that it is possible to write the covariant derivative of the tetrad $^{(4)}\nabla_a e_b$, in terms of the induced components of the hypersurface $e_a$ and the normal vector $\boldsymbol{n}$ in form
\begin{align}
^{(4)}\nabla_a e_b=-K_{ab}\boldsymbol{n}+^{(3)}\Gamma^{c}_{ba}e_c\,,
\end{align}
which is known as Gauss equation, obtained in Eq. (3.32). Although I project the normal vector in the extrinsic curvature equation, I obtain $K_{ab}\boldsymbol{n}=\underbrace{\boldsymbol{n}\cdot\boldsymbol{n}}_{-1}\cdot\,^{(4)}\nabla_a e_b=-^{(4)}\nabla_a e_b$, and no Christoffel symbol contribution. How this term appear?